# Were the aliens in "Signs" hostile?

Tags: signs

Were the aliens in *Signs* supposed to be hostile, in the sense that they were evil, or did they have some neutral intent that could not be understood by human standards?

Was the purpose of their arrival specified in the movie, and if it was, was the purpose hostile towards Earth or were the aliens just misunderstood by the humans?

Comment: Being hostile is not necessarily the same as being evil.  Though the more hostile someone is, the less likely they are to avoid being evil.

Answer (score 5):

As I recall (Alien Species Fandom backs confirms my memory) the "Signs" aliens came to Earth to harvest humans, although the reason for this harvest is not explained - whether they want us as food or slaves, or for a different purpose.

The quote below is from the [Alien Species Fandom website](https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_(Signs)).

> Although the reason for the alien's attack has never been officially stated, a survivor heard on the radio in the basement states that they came to harvest humans. He backs this up by stating that he and his friend saw the aliens poison his friend's family and drag away the bodies. This is extremely unusual, because the alien's weakness is water and 50-65% of human bodies are water. Now obviously they must not have known this beforehand. However, thanks to the family mentioned above, they must have definitely found out through them and then, realizing they messed up and are invading a planet whose surface and inhabitants are filled with the very substance that can kill them, promptly retreat and leave Earth.

In contemplation of the comments about the aliens' seemingly poor choice of harvest locations - considering that a vast proportion of the Earth's surface is composed of water, which is caustic to the aliens - I've speculated that human beings must contain something that the aliens need desperately, that they would risk landing in such an environment.

Comment: For a species capable of space travel, one would have thought that given something like 70% of the Earth's surface is water, they might have noticed an ocean or two and gone: "yeah - that's not a good idea" :p

Comment: Also, did any of them think to taste test humans before launching a planetary hunt for our meat?  Clearly not, given what we're mostly made of.  No, I'm afraid that, the more I think about it, the less this tale of an advanced interstellar species building a bunch of hyperdrives and taking them across light-years of space to barbecue their neighbors, only to be thwarted by farm folk huddling in the pantry, makes sense.

Comment: This appears to be a fan-written wiki. Can you offer any first-hand evidence to back this up?

Comment: My only first-hand evidence is my memory of that dialog from the film, that the aliens were harvesting humans. This does not technically indicate hostility, as gathering food (or whatever the aliens wanted us for)mis an act of survival, not aggression.

Comment: You do realise the aliens aren’t aliens; they’re demons. The whole movie is about faith, loss, and redemption. The water that hurts them isn’t just water, it’s holy water that was first discovered in “3 places in the Middle East” anyone want to bet on Jerusalem, Bethlehem, and Mecca?

Answer (score -1):

**We don't know**

I cannot find any canonical or authoritative evidence suggesting that the aliens were intended to be hostile or evil. Nor can I find any such evidence that the aliens considered themselves hostile or evil.

Comment: This answer appears to be very long on bold assertive statements and very short on actual, y'know, evidence.

Comment: @Valorum What evidence of the human perspective about an unknown circumstance do you think I need to provide?

Comment: OP is looking for what the *filmmakers* intended. What you've provided is your own personal interpretation.

Comment: @Valorum OK, pretty strict, but I've updated my answer. Would it be valuable to have tags such as [tag:authoritative] and [tag:speculation]? As written and tagged, I believe the assertion that the OP is looking for only what the filmakers intended is an assumption, especially since [tag:plot-explanation] appears to have been created by this OP for this question.

Comment: I don't think we need a tag for 'speculative', since all answers should be authoritative

Comment: Wasn't the whole "asthma saved child from inhaled poison" pretty indicative of evil actions?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson The alien who abducted the boy was the same alien that had its fingers cut off at the doctor's place, wasn't it? And though the boy was threatened, the poison wasn't injected until the uncle presented the baseball bat as a weapon. I'm not sure one justifiably angry alien reflects the intentions of the entire species.