# Are the knife/sword fights too fast in Dune (2021)?

Tags: dune, adaptation-comparison, dune-2021

"The slow knife penetrates the shield", we are told in both the *Dune* novel and its 2021 adaptation. Personal shields are meant to stop (or at least, severely slow down) fast-moving objects, such as projectiles or fast blade movements, but to let in slower-moving objects.

I always thought blade fighting in the *Dune* universe was supposed to be some sort of slow ballet where swords were swung slowly enough that they penetrate the shield yet fast enough to cause damage. Some sort of restrained yet impactful sword fighting.

However... when Duncan Idaho makes his stand against the Sardaukar, we see him doing extremely fast cuts and thrusts with his blades. He starts the fight by rushing head first into the mass of enemy troops and start making fast slashing movements that cut through the shield (which we see turn red, which means a penetrating hit).

How are his extremely fast movements bypassing the shields of his opponents?

Comment: I believe in the book they do move the knives swiftly, but the idea is to slow just before hitting the shield, and thus get through. When Paul fights Jamis, this is remarked upon by Stilgar because he thinks Paul is doing it to humiliate Jamis, when it is just habit ingrained from using a shield all his life.

Comment: @DafyddNZ yes, but do note how in this fight Duncan never even slows down a bit. He runs towards the Sardaukar and slashes furiously, no slow down at all.

Comment: I don't know much about filming or editing, but I imagine it would be hard to capture the speed and slow down in a visual format, without making it absurdly obvious. This could just be a limitation of the visual medium.

Comment: Also it would be extremely difficult to record a scene where hits move at 6 to 8 cms/s, as it's the velocity at which impacts pass through the shields (according to Dune wiki https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Shield) and make it to seem realistic and not forced or too choreographiated

Comment: You have 2-5 hours to present a book in film. What do you focus on? David Lynch chose to focus on "the slow blade penetrates the shield." Denis Villeneuve didn't. I can't even remember what John Harrison did in the SciFi/SciFy miniseries (which I remember thinking hit the book more closely than Dune 1984, although the costuming and casting was dubious). My point? You're wondering about the artistic interpretation of a director [who isn't bound to represent the book in any way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune). And Herbert never gave a maximum velocity, anyway.

Comment: Professional knife fighters move _much_ faster than that well-choreographed fight scene.

Comment: Hey all: some of you seem to be arguing from the real world, some seem to imply the movement is slow, and some simply think it's artistic license. All is welcome in answers that can be upvoted/downvoted; please risk it and post your replies :)

Comment: @JBH so is that your answer? That Villeneuve mentioned the speed and even showed a training session (with the catch phrase!), but for artistic reasons didn't follow through in Duncan's last stand? Ok, fair enough: are you willing to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @DoscoJones could you elaborate in a proper answer? The initial slash Duncan makes at the legs, with the sword, is full speed. Does it seem slow to you? (If you disagree, please write an answer that can be upvoted/downvoted).

Comment: @Bardo is that your answer? That the "proper" speed wouldn't look right on screen? Are you willing to turn it into an answer? :)

Comment: @JBH here's the training session with Gurney from the SyFy miniseries (which I didn't like much, by the way): fast slashes get deflected, and Paul's knife penetrates the shield reaaaal slooooooow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Or5viS20Oc&t=565s

Comment: @AndresF. I (probably like others) didn't post an answer because the question isn't about the canon of the story (aka, it's not about science fiction and fantasy) but *quite literally* about the artistic license of the director. I personally didn't take this to an answer because I suspected the question was off-topic and was expecting it to be voted closed. Are we judging artistic license on this Stack? That's highly opinion-based. There is no movie that perfectly expresses any book - especially when so much of the book is left to the imagination of the reader.

Comment: @JBH Agree with the sentiment, don't agree with the objections. It is not opinion based when asking about visualization of the concept which influenced millennia of human existence and progress and development (especially warfare). Shield is the reason the fight returned to "cold steel" weapons. Artistic license is one thing, making a farce of the cornerstone of the pictured universe's warfare and (to not repeat myself) lifestyle is another. I think question is valid, because for me this move is equivalent of making Bene Gesserit telepaths by Lynch (another farce of crucial plot element).

Comment: @AcePL Your own answer is just a stream of your own opinions (unless you can cite something said by the director?). Isn't the VTC:Opinion-Based reason specifically to avoid that? I've actually had [Valorum chastise me](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/275229/87710) for giving an answer of the nature exhibited by yours and Bardo's answers (if you care to look, read the edit history). Curiously, I didn't express any objections in my original comment. I simply pointed out that directors do things due to constraints that have nothing at all to do with story canon.

Comment: @JBH - I seem to have several facts there, not just opinions... And it answers the question as posted. As for the rest - I said I agree with the sentiment, as in: artistic license is a thing and must be respected. However, I also pointed out that his making stuff up in an area that has ultimate impact on the story canon - shields are the reason humanity in **Dune** reverted to combat with bladed weapons, which require a lifetime of training or an inner talent and some training to be successful... As I answered: in the movie they are useless as a tool, but they are a fundamental as a concept.

Comment: @JBH the question is not opinion based and scifi.se definitely allows questions about the (possible) mismatch between an adaptation and the source material. As you can see, there are no close votes at the moment :) Feel free to add one if you think it's off-topic for scifi though!

Comment: @AndresF. (\*sigh\*) Both of the answers below are simply summaries of canon that have nothing to do with directorial decisions and respondent opinions. My Meta post is evaluating the quality of the on-topic nature of questions like this. Popularity isn't proof that a question should or should not be closed on any Stack. And this entire debate started when I explained why I didn't answer your question. Were you offended that I didn't? Because it feels like it.

Comment: @JBH - I take offense to that characterization. ;-) I believe I tackled the artist vision some... And I believe my response can be read as a dedense of that vision, because... movies. I am of the opinion that Dune is one of those that are extremely hard to convert to a moving picture, so I am literally shrugging - yeah, so what? I'm waiting to see how the second part will do, because it's way more difficult to make right.

Comment: @JBH don't "sigh" me or assume I've been "offended". I've been here longer than you (12 vs 6 years), so don't pretend to teach me how this site works. Anyway, I and others disagree with you: deal with it! (Your feelings are your own: feel free to "feel" about stuff however you want).

Answer (score 11):

Part *"Terminology of the Imperium"* from the book **"Dune"** states that the speed limit of the Holzmann shield is adjustable within 6 to 9 centimeters per second ([Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dune0000herb_f4t1/page/528/mode/2up?q=shield)). And it is mentioned in the book that combat is not just about slow, penetrating hits, but also movement so that just the speed of it makes penetration very difficult.

The scene from the 2021 movie should show all the killing blows in a completely counter-intuitive way, that is - made with ***blade moving backwards*** - for it to be definitely "canon". And I just could see that done in the right way, making it another iconic fight scene next to **The Matrix**'s bullet-time ones.

It would take some effort to train and choreograph, but I am positive it would be great scene with evasive movements and counters to strikes to be very, very quick, while perfectly timed and aimed killing attacks be slow, very slow or (as I mentioned above) while the blade moves backwards to counter attacker's movement forward, for example. Training session would be fantastic, because it literally has a running commentary in the dialogues, better than with off-screen narrator voice...

So going back on topic - while that scene was beautifully done, it just made shield completely irrelevant... It does not show, at all, what it is and how it influences the plot, it's just flashy and very fluid.

And technically, it is a sensible move. Because shield is inconsequential across the series - it just goes away as a tool, remains basically only as a concept. But it would be great if they did at least one scene with the really book-compliant combat scene. Then you can technically forget the shield completely and everyone is happy...

Comment: I may be conflating real science into the thing, plus I am assuming that the shield is floating around the person (rather than acting like a second skin, since I've never watched nor read Dune), but it makes me wonder: if I put my arm half-way into the shield, slowly, then proceed to perform a 1-inch punch Bruce Lee style, would the shield activate and severe my arm by detecting it started moving too fast? Or would it assume it's okay since it entered slowly at first?

Comment: @Clockwork Imagine all the boot shaped divots taken out  of the floor too.

Comment: @Clockwork - If I remember correctly the shield is basically another layer on top of the body or outfit. There is a description of how it looks when people use it in the book (I can't find it right now), and it appears as a faint glimmer when moving. Nothing like the First movie or miniseries... If it's more like a coating than armor (and other bits of description contradict it some, TBH), then penetrating hit should do instant damage. Frankly physics of the shield are weird: if your shield is active, does it encompass your blade, and if yes, does it and enemy shield mesh when slow enough?

Comment: @Clockwork 2/2 - All those issues are why I say one fight should be enough. I think movie would be much better if that shield-involved fight would be the training session and Idaho's last stand would be literally off screen, with sound only... After that shield is irrelevant, basically, for ever, in HtH combat.

Comment: +1 Well reasoned and justified. I do think the scene is pretty cool. This essentially boils down to "yes, Duncan is going too fast for the book canon, but this looks cool and shields are not so important a point anyway".

Comment: @Clockwork I don’t think the shield “decides” much, especially given the prohibition on thinking machines. I’ve always interpreted it as being a force field that acts like a shear-thickening fluid, providing very little resistance to slow motion, but ramping up quickly with faster motion. You’d feel a force in the cross section of your arm where it intersects the shield, and probably wouldn’t have enough momentum in your fist to tear your arm apart.

Comment: @RLH You mean like non-newtonian fluid?

Comment: @Clockwork: Yes. ("Shear-thickening" fluids become stiffer under impact -- think oobleck -- whereas "shear-thinning" fluids flow more easily under impact -- think ketchup or other sauce stuck in a bottle until you hit the bottle, at which point it all runs out. Both are examples of non-Newtonian fluid, which just means "a fluid with more complicated behavior than the reference minimal model for how a fluid works".)

Comment: Minor correction but the 6-9 cm/s thing is not from Appendix IV, it's from the entry for "shield" in the "Terminology of the Imperium" section which comes after Appendix IV. Also, I don't understand why you say that showing it correctly would involve the "blade moving backwards"? I thought it was still a normal stabbing motion but just a slow one done when the person had been pinned down. You can get a feel for how slow it'd be if you have a ruler that's at least 45 cm long--at 9 cm/s it should take you 5 seconds to move your hand from 0 cm to 45 cm.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - speed of the penetration is not for the attacker, but also for the defender. So, in case of the 2021 movie scene with Duncan Idaho defending the passage, the sardaukar were attacking, with their movement forward. If they were moving with a speed greater than 6-9 cm/s (which they obviously will be), then Idaho must almost match that movement  to achieve resultant velocity of the tip of his knife to under 6-9 cm/s. Again, obviously. So if sardaukar moves at 45 cm/s (for example), then Idaho must move his knife backwards at speed of between 45 to 36 cm/s.

Comment: @AcePL - Good point, nearly matching speeds might be a way to get through the shield, though I thought from the descriptions that the main tactic was getting one's opponent to stop moving momentarily and slip the blade in then, as when Paul tried to trap Gurney Halleck by getting his rapier to catch on the table.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I would like to point you to the Paul - Chanis fight... It's without shields, obviously, but Paul is fighting there as if Chanis wore one. Classic duel with blows, parries and counterblows, no traps etc. Also, a side note - thanks for pointing out the *Appendic IV* business - that was embarrassing

Comment: My reading of the sequence is that the blades can still move faster - it's just that they'll hit the shield, stop, and then essentially *become* a slower moving object for the final stages. They do show the shields briefly going blue before going red, and it's my understanding that that's the "Activating the shield barrier", then "It going slow enough to make some progress". See also, that one dart attack attempting to pierce the shield of the Duke just before the invasion itself began. Bullets don't work because they can't slow down that fast, and so "Bounce" off the shields immediately.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st - that goes against the book, and in the movie it's not explained - because book states (when Paul taunts Gurney during practice session): if penetrator moves too fast, it is deflected, not stopped... But it is an interesting point and would, most certainly, work in a movie and, in fact, it would make shield relevant without making it relevant.

Answer (score 5):

According to Dune wiki, shields let pass moving objets that are slower than 6 to 8 cms/s, and stop any moving object faster than that (https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Shield).

This means that a fight choreography for the scene, where movements seems natural and realistic for a fight (you know... with people trying actively to avoid being stabbed), but where knives slowing down to a proper speed to avoid shields just before impact, would be extremely difficult to design, execute and shot.

First of all, it will be very difficult to design it, as almost any hand to hand combat movement relays in speed as one of it's primary characteristics. Usually scenes are designed like a sort of a dance between sparrings, performers train the scene at a slow pace and build movement and speed as they get used to the scene. Almost anything that would be designed to slow dramatically the pace just before the impact would seem "choreographiated" on screen, giving the sensation of a dance more than a fight to the death.

Also, making fast movements on a fight scene, slowing down just instants before making an impact is something extremely difficult to accomplish, and even being able to do it "properly", it will result quite odd to external viewers. Shooting such a scene, and achieve a result visually exciting and thrilling would be much more difficult (and expensive) than just shooting a "standard" fight scene.

We've seen a lot of times how scripts and it's peculiarities have to bend to cinema language so certain scenes can be shot, this is surely one more of that situations

Comment: The cited fandom doesn't seem to reference the sources from where the 6 to 8 cm/s figure comes from.

Comment: @Clockwork - this is written in *Appendix IV"* of the **"Dune"** book, where it says 6 to 9 cm/s- about 270 meters per hour, which is ridiculously slow (normal walk is about 140 cm per second or 5 kilometers per hour). Scene from 2020 Movie is definitely not "canon", and while it was beautifully done, it just made shield obsolete.

Comment: +1 Seems reasonable enough to me. Yes, this is a case where the visual medium doesn't fit the written page. I think they could have made an effort anyway, but seeing as the fights in this adaptation look way better than all others, they must have made the right call!